# Visual Studio DB Project Post-Deploy Events

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I currently have a Database Project in Visual Studio 2012 which will deploy a database to my server. I'd like to then populate this database with test data automatically, and have a SQL Generator 3 project (Redgate Tools) which can do so via command line.

The problem I am having is that while I can add the command line execution as a post-build event, I cannot find a way of adding it as a post-*deploy* event. Ideally I'd want to publish the database and then run the test data generator to populate it, all automatically and in one swoop through Visual Studio.

Does anybody know of a way of achieving this? All I've found so far is SQLCMD post-deploy scripts which I don't believe will let me run external executables.

Answer (score 0):

Example using pre/post build events:

```
   COPY /Y "$(TargetDir)MyDll.dll" "C:\Program Files\SomeFolder" 
   TASKKILL /F /IM MyProgramm.exe
```

Comment: The issue with post-build events is that they fire _before_ a database is published from a database project. I need an executable to fire afterwards.

Comment: Click rigth mouse button on your DB project and choose Add->Script>PostDeployment

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm being unclear. Post deployment scripts are sql only, and I want to run an executable instead of some SQL code.

Comment: May be your need use [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) `xp_cmdshell procedure` to run your .EXE file?